# How do I prove that $A'=C_{u,v}AC_{u,v}^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $A'$, the matrix of a linear operator, $L$, with respect to a basis, $\{v_i\}$, is given by $C_{u,v}AC_{u,v}^{-1}$, where $A$ is the matrix of the same linear operator with respect to a different basis, ${u_i}$, and $C_{u,v}=V^{-1}U$, where $U,V$, are the column matrices for their respective bases. I understand that we find, $A$, by applying $L$ to all the $u_i$, and $A'$, by applying $L$ to all the $v_i$, but I'm not sure how to use this to prove this statement. A nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition, $\sum_k x_k u_k = \sum_k [C_{u,v} x]v_k$.

$L (\sum_k x_k u_k) = \sum_k [Ax]_k u_k = \sum_k [C_{u,v} Ax]v_k$.

$L (\sum_k x_k u_k) = L(\sum_k [C_{u,v} x]v_k) = \sum_k [A'C_{u,v} x]v_k$.

It follows that $C_{u,v} Ax = A'C_{u,v} x$ for all $x$ and hence $C_{u,v} A = A'C_{u,v}$.